# How to stop send email for a specific recipient for specific order status types when change order status in woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

This code is working for `completed` order status but not working for `assembly` status. How can I target the `assembly` status as well?

Thank you.

```php
    add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_recipient_customer_assembly_order', 'hoodsly_email_recipient_customization', 10, 2 );
    
    function hoodsly_email_recipient_customization( $recipient, $order ) {
        if( $order->get_billing_email() == 'example@email.com' ) {
            $recipient = '';
        }
        return $recipient; 
    }
```

Comment: "assembly status" is not a default WooCommerce order status. You will therefore have to provide more information about this order status, if it is obtained through the use of a plugin then I must point out that questions about 3rd party plugins should be asked directly to the plugin support.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply. I am using WooCommerce Order Status Manager plugin to create custom status. https://woocommerce.com/products/woocommerce-order-status-manager/

Comment: As I mentioned, questions about 3rd party plugins should be asked directly to the plugin support